# Reading data into Python

Tags: python

I have made a save file using

```
def Save():
    savefile = open('save.txt','w')
    savefile.write(str(currentLocation)+'\n')
    savefile.close()
    print("GAME SAVED!", file=sys.stderr)
```

which works fine but when I go to load it using...

```
def Load():
    savefile = open('save.txt', 'r')
    for line in savefile:
        currentLocation.append(currentLocation)
    savefile.close()
```

I get an error called :

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'.
```

Any reason you can think of why this doesn't work?

Comment: It means that `currentLocation` is an `int` - not a `list`. BTW, are you sure you want to `currentLocation.append(currentLocation)` (append a list to itself) ? you probably want something like: `currentLocation.append(line)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append to a non-list type object:

**currentLocation** is not a list

If your file only contains one line (with the number to load), then you can read the file and strip the contents to get the number without new lines, spaces, etc.

```
def Load():
    with open('save.txt', 'r') as loadfile:
        currentLocation = int(loadfile.read().strip())
```

The above **with** statement will automatically close the file after the nested block of code.

There is also **int casting** to convert the read number from string to int.

Comment: How would I replace the value then? I have only learnt how to read into lists, how would you do it with an integer?

Comment: @Goonertron I would need to see more code. Update your question with more code so I can help you.

Comment: currentLocation = 0 is the variable that gets updated and when I save it into a text file it shows the number like 4 for example which is correct, I just can't figure out how to replace the 0 in current location with the number saved in the text file.

Comment: Let me know if the new answer helps.